# amazon payment gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services

Am doing one project ,

For that my client asked amazon payment gateway ,

So now i started exploring amazon payment gateway ,

This is the first time am looking the amazon payment gateway ,

I have registered in amazon payment gateway,

Please tell me  PHP CODE  snippet for amazon payment gateway ,

Thanks

Comment: People here will not in general 'send you the code'. If you want code, you should google for samples and libraries. If you write code and need help with it, post your specific question here.

Comment: What a wonderful poem! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Amazon has different payment products.  [Checkout by Amazon](https://payments.amazon.com/sdui/sdui/business/cba) is their usual product, but it works best for products that you actually ship by mail.  [SimplePay](https://payments.amazon.com/sdui/sdui/business/asp;jsessionid=BFAD34A04E94F492605FF690D3683B06) is probably best for electronic goods and services - which I discovered too late.  Make sure you sign up for the right thing.  :)

Here's the PHP code for a "Pay Now" button for one item using a POST form submission:

```
// Key from Amazon
$merchant_id = 'your_id';
$aws_access_key_id = 'your_access_key'; 
$aws_secret_access_key = 'your_secret_access_key';

// Set up cart
$form['aws_access_key_id'] = $aws_access_key_id;
$form['currency_code'] = 'USD';
$form['item_merchant_id_1'] = $merchant_id;
$form['item_price_1'] = $price;
$form['item_quantity_1'] = $quantity;
$form['item_sku_1'] = $sku;
$form['item_title_1'] = $item_name;
ksort($form);

// Encode order as string and calculate signature
$order = '';
foreach ($form as $key => $value) {
  $order .= $key . "=" . rawurlencode($value) . "&";
}
$form['merchant_signature'] = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $order, $aws_secret_access_key, true));

// Return string with Amazon javascript and HTML form
// Assumes you already have jQuery loaded elsewhere on page
// URL's link to live site, not sandbox!
$amazon_order_html = 
  '<script type="text/javascript" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/cba/js/widget/widget.js"></script>
  <form method="post" action="https://payments.amazon.com/checkout/' . $merchant_id . '">';
foreach ( $form as $key => $value ) {   
  $amazon_order_html .= '<input type="hidden" name="' . $key . '" value="' . $value . '" />';
}
$amazon_order_html .= '<input alt="Checkout with Amazon Payments" src="https://payments.amazon.com/gp/cba/button?ie=UTF8&color=orange&background=white&cartOwnerId=' . $merchant_id . '&size=large" type="image"></form>';

return $amazon_order_html;
```

Comment: i have your_access_key and your_secret_access_key , Wher ei go for merchant ID, can u tell me URL for merchant ID

Comment: Account Number is Merchant Id ? 

Or merchant id somthing Diff ?

Answer (score 0):

For simple pay when account is created, user will be given a sandbox access in which you find the "Merchant code" at this URL : https://sandbox.simplepay.hu/admin/partner/account/id(partnerid)